# My USB devices sometimes flicker on boot

Tags: usb, motherboard, power

I have a problem with a PC where the power sometimes acts up on boot. This PC has a mouse with back-lighting. The back-lighting on the mouse will 'sometimes' flicker and the PC will not accept any input from the mouse. When this happens the USB keyboard will also boot with troubles. Rather than flickering (it has back-lighting too) it will simply not power (No input here either.) Now, this sounds like a motherboard issue, except for one thing I am hoping somebody can explain:

If I disconnect the devices and reconnect them everything starts working again. No restart is required or anything of the sort. What might be the problem and is there a fix short of a new motherboard?

Edit:

Some new information: It seems that the mouse is where everything is going wrong. I have reinstalled motherboard drivers, disabled superfetch, and disabled readyboot. None of this has helped the issue. I have determined however that it seems to start the trouble with the mouse. If I unplug the mouse and plug it back in, everything goes back on track (the keyboard begins to work.)

Comment: First of all, try the devices on another computer if possible. Second, consider checking things besides the motherboard like the power supply. Third, reconnecting would reinitialize the devices and thus fix an incorrect initialization. Device LEDs lighting up is usually normal upon boot, does your lighting-up differ from that?

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, when I say boot, I mean at the windows start screen.

Comment: @Serodis Which OS? Does it ever fix itself in time? (max time I would possibly give it 3-5min) .   Did this happen when you first installed?

Comment: This didn't happen at first, it is Windows Vista and the items work fine on other computers. It also seems that it only starts flashing once Windows starts. This happens BEFORE login.

Comment: @Serodis the reason I ask is because on my own system, the faster the readyboot stuff attempts to make my boot, the more thrashing and out of order, and collisions it creates, for me it is mostly after log-in, but I autolog locally. I am wondering for myself if i should toss this "feature" or clear it, my boot is not slow, to be needing it.  Enumerating 50 drivers at a time, while running 10 pieces of software, with 89 services starting :-) Then with the overprotection of a stalled item.

Comment: @psycogeek I have not seen if it fixes itself. The most I've let it sit is about two minutes, so I can't be entirely sure.

Comment: @TomWijsman Where does initialization take place? I would assume if unplugging and replugging the device fixes it that the power-supply must be providing proper power, especially if it only happens on boot? Does the motherboard do anything that would fix such an issue when you simply plug something in? Or.. is it most likely a driver problem?

Comment: @Serodis: I can't tell for sure, I'm just saying that it causes a reinitialization somewhere. Which are the three possible things you have mentioned...

Comment: During the post/init/boot/startup, is when the highest load can exist on the power supply itself, and the power regulations on the motherboard, etc.  (aka I agree that it is possible to be a power issue) If it acted different on Power-up Vrses Restart , that could be another clue.

Comment: My only thought as far as power goes, is that it should be using less, and I've yet to see this occur during usage, only during boot. This is a gaming PC and has a high-power video-card (HD 6870) which shouldn't consume much during boot as compared to when the CPU/GPU are running full power. Plus, the user of the machine constantly uses WAY too much memory and has caching causing disk-usage as well. Never has this occurred at this time. I am going to look into BIOS updates as well as mother-board drivers and continue monitoring when and how the PC reacts. (Am I wrong about the power?)

Comment: There is no wrong :-) other than the thing not working right :-) OCCT (stability/power testing) could be used to beat the heck out of the system harder than games would ever, to check for the MAX usage. . . . Try clearing the prefetch, disable fastboot features and superfetch. try booting in other Modes (like safe does it do it them?), try disabling a few drivers, at least the unnessisary ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check "devices by connection" in device manager - maybe mouse is oversubscribing power on USB hub shared with e.g builtin webcam and pluging it into other USB port easily solves the problem

Comment: Going to do some testing this weekend, I will come back to the question.

Comment: Looks like I may have found the problem. The computer in question has a keyboard with a built-in low-power USB hub. This hub seems to have been failing on boot. I am going to test this to be sure, but it seems the most likely. Oddly, when checking devices by connection, however, it lists it as a sibling rather than a child and I wasn't aware the PC had been setup in such a way. I will come back after further testing to accept if it no longer fails.

Comment: Yes - each thing connected draws power from USB. If that hub was parent it would just add a bit of latency to say USB hadphone